# Use a DATE() function in a WHERE clause with DQL

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I get a strange error when I execute this DQL query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN u.schedule s WHERE DATE(s.timestamp) = DATE(NOW())
```

The exception is thrown by Doctrine with the message:

```
Expected known function, got 'DATE'
```

The problem looks similar to [this bug](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1236), but that addresses the DATE() function in a GROUP BY clause and the bug is closed for Doctrine 2.2. At this moment, I get the exception with doctrine 2.4-DEV.

The query is meant to select all users scheduled for today. Is there any way I can create this DQL? I tested the SQL version in phpMyAdmin and there the query does not raise an error. What might be wrong?

Comment: Doctrine2 DQL doesn't have a DATE() or NOW() function: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions. But do you really want to compare two timestamp on their equality?

Comment: I have scheduled patients for an appointment (date + time) and I want to list all patients for today. There is an ugly way to do this: prepare the statement with a php `DateTime` object for "today". And split the datetime field into a "date" and "time" part. I can overcome the first ugly part, but the second is just screwing with your db because an abstraction layer problem. So that's why I hoped for a solution where this would work :) I tried a `SELECT CAST(s.timestamp as DATE) as schedule_day FROM ... WHERE schedule_day = :today` but it returned a similar error...

Answer (score 31):

You can achieve what you want by using a [custom function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html):

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

class DateFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    private $arg;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf('DATE(%s)', $this->arg->dispatch($sqlWalker));
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->arg = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

Then registering this function in your code:

```php
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DATE', 'DateFunction');
```

And your DQL query will work!

Comment: WIll try, thanks! This could save me a lot of headaches where I'd have split the scheduled timestamp in a separated day and time part

Comment: Here is how to register the new DQL function in a Symfony2 app: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Comment: Also don't forget to put namespace definition in you class, otherwise symfony will complain class was not found in file.

Comment: There is a very cool composer package for that which includes almost every MySQL function:
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions Also see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html to register the functions.

Comment: When I try this my DATE() function returns a string not a DateTime... is there a missing configuration option to tell the ORM... "this string should be a DateTime"?