# symfony2: select from Table where start=today

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The "start" is a dateTime. I'm trying to get all rows that have "start" = Today without considering the hours and mins.
This what I did so far.
Only events with this form 'Y-m-d 00:00:00' are selected

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $onthisday = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT e
        FROM ECMEventBundle:Events e
        WHERE e.start = CURRENT_DATE()

        AND e.eventcreator = :userId'
    )->setParameter ( 'userId', $user->getId () );

    $todayEvent = $onthisday->getResult();
```

Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to register a [*date function*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272224/use-a-date-function-in-a-where-clause-with-dql) first for doctrine to understand then use `WHERE DATE(e.start)=CURRENT_DATE()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use php DateTime class:

```
$myDate = new \DateTime();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $onthisday = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT e
        FROM ECMEventBundle:Events e
        WHERE e.start > :myDate

        AND e.eventcreator = :userId'
    )->setParameter ( 'userId', $user->getId () )
    ->setParameter ( 'myDate', $myDate->format('Y-m-d 0:0:0') );
```

Comment: It should be backslash - `\DateTime();`

Comment: I wanted to compare years, months and days without considering the rest.

Comment: beacause i put hour min and sec to 0 and use > for comparison so it does what u want without considering hour...
I guess