# Execute date function in Symfony2 query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to execute `date()` function in Symfony2 query, below is what I've have tried but it gives me an error.

```
$query=$em->createQueryBuilder()
           ->select('date(a.created_at), COUNT(date( a.created_at) ) AS        count_user')
           ->from('ContrateAdminBundle:Artist', 'a')
           ->where("date(a.created_at) BETWEEN '{$fromdateCelebrities}' AND '{$todateCelebrities}'")
           ->groupBy('date(a.created_at)')
           ->getQuery();
```

I have also pasted the output string of my query, which I can execute without any error directly in MySQL.

```
select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from Artist where date(created_at) BETWEEN '2015-01-05' AND '2015-02-25' group by date(created_at)
```

Comment: Could you just use the sql function DATE()?

Comment: how can i used sql function DATE()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select entries between dates in doctrine 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553183/select-entries-between-dates-in-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused by doctrine 2, it does not understand the mysql method `date`, you should create it manualy.

I saw the sollution alredy on [Create custom Doctrine 2 Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272224/use-a-date-function-in-a-where-clause-with-dql)

- Create a php class named DateFunction.php with the following code:

  ```
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

  class DateFunction extends FunctionNode
  {
      private $arg;

      public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
      {
          return sprintf('DATE(%s)', $this->arg->dispatch($sqlWalker));
      }

      public function parse(Parser $parser)
      {
          $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
          $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

          $this->arg = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

          $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
      }
  }
  ```
- In your controller or repository after you got the `$em` register the new method

  `$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomDatetimeFunction('DATE', 'DateFunction');`

This will register your custom doctrine method;

Comment: can you give me the solution because i am totally new on symfony2

Comment: i am going to try this if still i have faced any problem then i`ll let you know

Comment: where can i create this class?

Comment: I'l sugest to make a folder in your bundle `DoctrineCustomFunctions` or `DoctrineFunctions` and place it there, or you can use the Symfony 2 sugested way, create the `DQL` folder and place them there, you can then make them global by configuring them in config.yml follow the link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

Comment: is there anyother simple method for doing this.Because i am totally new on symfony2 and i have no idea about more on this

Comment: This is the way Doctrine 2 works, can't help you more